# how to check different version of same file using python

Tags: python, regex, string

I have list of files two lists (A and B). I am comparing the file names in list A with B. I want to know whether the latest version of the files is available in List B when doing comparison.

For example:

List A contains - **id_prot_number_f1_v1_p1**  and List B contains **id_prot_number_f1_v2_p1** - In this case I want to get match instead of non match.  Currently I am using in function of python to check the existence of file in List.

is there any way i can check latest version available in another list ?

Comment: do you mean you want to compare the `v*` in your file name with another?

Comment: please provide samples along your expected output

Comment: In your own words, can you identify what part of the string in list B must also be present in list A for there to be a match? In addition to this, what condition needs to be true to say that the version in list B is an update to the version in list A? Programming will be very easy if you start to break your problem down into simpler jobs and try to solve those jobs. You might even find pre-existing solutions for similar problems, so you'll get your answers quicker than having to wait some time for answers to your question!